# Is there an attribute that can show which process created a file?

Tags: macos, uti

Now, I can find out which processes are opening files dynamically.  However, for a file on my filesystem, is there a way to find out which process *created* the file?

I'm trying to differentiate a file I created by:

```
touch(1)
```

from one created by say, an NSAPI process running under my id.

```
lastcomm(1)
```

will give me information such as which tty is doing something, is that an attribute I can access?

Essentially, my id does a bunch of stuff.  Much of what my id does should be via applications, or from a terminal.  I'd like to find out more.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darwin is open source. I'm guessing you'll need to modify OS level things, a kernel extension, etc. and add this ability.

Or you could modify the dynamic-view tools you know (`fs_usage` and/or `lsof`), have them check if a file is being created, and append the process chain that created it into the Spotlight comment, etc.